# Test struct for at least one non null value

Tags: google-bigquery

Given the data set:

| field_a | description_1 | metric_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ball | large | 20 |
| ball | small | 4 |
| cat | *null* | *null* |

I want to pack fields description_1 and metric_1 into a struct and then zip them into an array by field_a:

```
WITH
  DATA AS (
  SELECT
    'ball' AS field_a,
    'large' AS description_1,
    20 AS metric_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'ball',
    'small',
    4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'cat',
    NULL,
    NULL )
SELECT
  field_a,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(description_1,
      metric_1))
FROM
  DATA
GROUP BY
  1;
```

That gives me:

[image]

However, if all fields in the struct are null I would like to see an empty array instead of an array with size of 1 and an struct inside of it.

Desired output:

[image]

I figured the following query to test the fields before packing them into the struct:

```
WITH
  DATA AS (
  SELECT
    'ball' AS field_a,
    'large' AS description_1,
    20 AS metric_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'ball' AS field_a,
    'small',
    4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'cat',
    NULL,
    NULL )
SELECT
  field_a,
  ARRAY_AGG(
  IF
    (description_1 IS NOT NULL
      OR metric_1 IS NOT NULL,
      STRUCT(description_1,
        metric_1),
      NULL)IGNORE NULLS)
FROM
  DATA
GROUP BY
  1;
```

However it feels like a tedious solution, is there a better way to test if struct contains at least one non-null value? or any other solution to achieve the desired output more elegantly?

Answer (score 2):

Below approach might be slightly cleaner one

```
select * from (select distinct field_a from your_table)
left join (
  select field_a, array_agg(struct(description_1, metric_1)) 
  from your_table
  where not description_1 is null and not metric_1 is null
  group by field_a
)
using(field_a)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: there are more ways to write that `where` clause and depends on your tastes

for example

```
where format('%t', (description_1, metric_1)) != '(NULL, NULL)'
```

or

```
where to_json_string((description_1, metric_1)) != '{"":null,"":null}'
```

But, I feel, using explicit `not ... is ...` is more natural and explicit so easier to swallow if you have just two or three columns to check.

When you have more - like 5 or 10, etc. last two version can produce more compact code ...